# Как создать подобную диаграмму в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Вопрос такой, как возможно создать похожую диаграмму? Ширина каждой категории должна быть одинаковой, а в зависимости от значения, в каждой ячейке будет либо же у центра, либо же на самом краю. Из чего то похожего, что я нашёл в интернете, это полярная диаграмма, но я не нашёл способ по крайней мере убрать у неё значения углов в градусах.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимально похожее, что я могу придумать, это такое решение (на основе второго примера [отсюда](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-a-pie-chart-in-python-using-matplotlib/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {"Самореализация": 9, "Духовность": 10, "Здоровье": 9, "Работа, деньги": 7,
       "Окружение": 8, "Личные отношения, семья": 9, "Отдых": 10, "Личностный рост": 8}
 
colors = ["darkorange", "darkviolet", "yellowgreen", "dodgerblue", "crimson", "deeppink", "green", "cyan"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(8, 8), subplot_kw = dict(polar = True))


norm = np.full(len(data), 1/len(data))*2*np.pi
left = np.cumsum(np.append(0, norm[:-1]))


ax.bar(x = left,
       width = norm,
       bottom = 0,
       height = [max(data.values())]*len(data),
       color = colors,
       edgecolor ='w',
       linewidth = 2,
       align ="edge",
       alpha = .2)

for n, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    ax.annotate(list(data.keys())[n],
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2,
                    p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                   size=15, xytext=(0, 8), color=colors[n],
                   textcoords='offset points')

ax.bar(x = left,
       width = norm,
       bottom = 0,
       height = data.values(),
       color = colors,
       edgecolor ='w',
       linewidth = 2,
       align ="edge",
       alpha = 1)

for n, p in enumerate(ax.patches[len(data):]):
    ax.annotate(p.get_height(),
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2,
                    p.get_height()-1), ha='center', va='center',
                   size=15, xytext=(0, 8), color="w",#color=colors[n],
                   textcoords='offset points')



ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

Получите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

разбираться с выравниванием аннотаций что-то нет ни времени ни желания, возможно будет лучше вообще из вывести как легенду и не перегружать код.